# Adding a 1-dimensional list to a 2D list

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int make_2d_arr(int x, int y){
     int **last = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*y);
     for (int i=0;i<y;++i){
          last[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*x);
     }
     return last;
}

int main(){
     int *example_arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
     int **last = make_2d_arr(3,4);
     example_arr[0] = 11;
     example_arr[1] = 22;
     example_arr[2] = 33;
     last[1] = example_arr;
     return 0;
}
```

My code is like above. And as you can imagine I'm getting "segmentation fault".
I want to do is add a one dimensional Array to a two dimensional Array.
How can I do this properly and without error?
Should I write a code like the one below?

```
...

void add_2d_arr_1d(int **two_dimensional_arr, int *one_dimensional, int index_2d, int len_one_dimensional){
     for (int i=0;i<len_one_dimensional;++i){
           two_dimensional[index_2d][i] = one_dimensional[i];
     }
}
...
```

!!!The "add_2d_arr_1d" function above has been added in addition to the first code I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the function type problem addressed in @MarkSouls answer, it is unclear why you use `x`, `y`, (presumably `rows` and `cols`) and allocate for `y` rows of `x` cols? It appears transposed, but regardless if they are backwards, simply rearranging will correct the rows/cols issue.

You need to understand that when allocating to simulate a 2D array (there is actually no array involved whatsoever), you have a two step process. You must first allocate `rows` number of pointers and assign the beginning address to `last`. Then you must loop `rows` times allocating storage for `cols` number of integers and assigning the beginning address to each of your pointers in turn.

You must also ***Validate*** EVERY allocation by checking the return to ensure that storage was allocated, if not `malloc()` (`calloc()`, and `realloc()`) will return `NULL` on failure. You need to handle that error. Additionally, in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

When simulating a 2D array, if, as in your case, you are not explicitly initializing each value, you should consider using `calloc()` to allocate and set all bytes zero to ensure you don't accidentally read from an uninitialized memory address.

Putting that together, your `make_2d_arr()` function could be written as:

```
int **make_2d_arr (int rows, int cols)
{
    int **last = malloc (sizeof *last * rows);      /* allocate rows number of pointers */
    
    if (!last) {                                    /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-last");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                /* loop rows times */
        last[i] = calloc (cols, sizeof *last[i]);   /* allocate/initialize cols int */
        if (!last[i]) {                             /* validate EVERY allocation */
            perror ("calloc-last[i]");
            while (i--)                             /* loop to free prior allocations */
                free (last[i]);                     /* free each row of int */
            free (last);                            /* free pointers */
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
    return last;            /* on success return pointer to allocated block of pointers */
}
```

(**note:** when allocating `cols` worth of `int` for each row, if `calloc()` fails, you need to `free()` all previously allocated rows and then free the pointers before returning `NULL` to avoid creating a memory leak.)

You cannot assign blocks of memory without overwriting your original `last[1]` pointer with:

```
last[1] = example_arr;
```

When this occurs, the original address for the allocated integers for `last[1]` is overwritten with the address for `example_array`. The `last[1]` pointer is lost and you have no way to free the memory you allocated. Instead, you need to copy the contents of `example_arr` to the 2nd row in your simulated 2D array. Simply include `string.h` and:

```
    /* you cannot overwrite pointers, you must copy (or loop and assign each) */
    memcpy (last[1], example_arr, rows * sizeof *example_arr);
```

Putting together a full example and rearranging your filling of `example_arr` to a simple loop, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int **make_2d_arr (int rows, int cols)
{
    int **last = malloc (sizeof *last * rows);      /* allocate rows number of pointers */
    
    if (!last) {                                    /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-last");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                /* loop rows times */
        last[i] = calloc (cols, sizeof *last[i]);   /* allocate/initialize cols int */
        if (!last[i]) {                             /* validate EVERY allocation */
            perror ("calloc-last[i]");
            while (i--)                             /* loop to free prior allocations */
                free (last[i]);                     /* free each row of int */
            free (last);                            /* free pointers */
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
    return last;            /* on success return pointer to allocated block of pointers */
}

int main (void) {
    
    int *example_arr, **last, rows = 3, cols = 4;   /* declarations */
    
    /* allocate / validate for example_arr */
    if (!(example_arr = malloc (sizeof *example_arr * 3)))
        return 1;
    
    /* call make_2d_arr / validate return */
    if (!(last = make_2d_arr (rows, cols)))
        return 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)                      /* loop adding your 3 values */
        example_arr[i] = (i + 1) * 11;
    
    /* you cannot overwrite pointers, you must copy (or loop and assign each) */
    memcpy (last[1], example_arr, rows * sizeof *example_arr);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                    /* loop rows */
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)                  /* loop cols */
            printf (j ? ", %2d" : "%2d", last[i][j]);   /* output results */
        putchar ('\n');                                 /* separate with newline */
        free (last[i]);                                 /* free ints when done */
    }
    free (last);            /* free pointers at end */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/example_arr_last
 0,  0,  0,  0
11, 22, 33,  0
 0,  0,  0,  0
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/example_arr_last
==15454== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15454== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15454== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15454== Command: ./bin/example_arr_last
==15454==
 0,  0,  0,  0
11, 22, 33,  0
 0,  0,  0,  0
==15454==
==15454== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15454==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15454==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 1,108 bytes allocated
==15454==
==15454== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15454==
==15454== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15454== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault is due to wrong function signature. You should change

```
int make_2d_arr(int x, int y)
```

to

```
int** make_2d_arr(int x, int y)
```